# R Studio: ctrl+shift+enter runs the entire code instead of the selected lines only

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R Studio and I have encountered a problem:  ctrl+shift+enter is running the entire code instead of the selected lines only. I can always use "Run", but I am used to  ctrl+shift+enter... Anybody has any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: I've always used ctrl+enter to run selected lines.

Comment: Thank you, I must have gotten confused with another program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Documentation [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

`Run current line/selection                             Ctrl+Enter`
`Run current line/selection (retain cursor position)    Alt+Enter`

Comment: Thanks for the Alt+Enter tip!

Comment: @Josh your very welcome! Delighted to hear that the information is still helpful. Best of luck with your analysis

Answer (score 2):

To run only what you have selected, use ctrl+enter (cmd+enter on mac). Leave off the shift.

Check out the following link for a cheatsheet with many RStudio commands.

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/